# nodemailer check if the mail has been sent

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer with nodejs express.

What I want to know is if my mail is sent successfully to the recipient. My mail service belongs to zoho.com.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

 let transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.zoho.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
      user: 'info@mymail.gr', 

      pass: '******', 
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    } 
  });

let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Test mail" <info@mymail.gr>', // sender address
    to: "infodasfdfs23432d@mymail.gr", // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
  }, (error, result) => {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
  });
```

The mail "infodasfdfs23432d@mymail.gr" it doesn't exist and the error is not triggered. How to check if my mail is delivered or not, with nodemailer?

Comment: Remove the `return` in the callback

Comment: I didn't get any changes. The error is not detected.

Comment: If it is a free service I could use it. But is has 14 days trial which is not an ideal solution.

Comment: SendinBlue is completely free giving you access to send 300 mails a day on the free account so that is more than enough I believe unless you are running a company then you will need to upgrade

Comment: Ok, how to do this verification?

Answer (score 1):

Nodemailer can simply pass the message to the relay, and from here Nodemailer gives response of the api.
And that's why there will no error occur for invalid e-mail address.

Comment: Yes, I figure out that. How is it possible to solve this problem with nodemailer?

Comment: It's not possible to achieve that with nodemailer.